# iPhone, how does one read an image from the photo library as NSData?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata

On the iPhone I saved an image to the photo library with modifications (appending data after the image code) using the assest library to save the NSData directly to the photo library. Now I want to read the image back from the photo library as an NSData to read it. If I read it as a UIImage, it changes the data inside the image.

How can I read the photo from the photo library as NSData? I tried looking into the reference URL in 4.1 but no luck.

Edit: I edited to explain why I'm saving it as an NSData. The URL method in the answers works if you just want pure NSData, but does not help in the context that I am asking.

Edit 2: The answer with the getBytes was the answer that did it for me. The code I used was:

```
int8_t *bytes = malloc([representation size]);
NSUInteger length = [representation getBytes:bytes fromOffset:0 length:[representation size] error:&error];
```

This was able to get me everything inside the file which gave me the image code PLUS what I added in NSData form.

**Edit 3:**

Is there a way to do this now in iOS 10 with the PHPhotoLibrary which replaces AssetLibrary? I need the image in NSData being the original RAW image with no modifications.

Comment: if you want to save image to photo library  then why you save it as a NSData ? save it as a UIimage.

Comment: I save it as NSData as I'm appending hidden messages in the image after the image tag ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into the getBytes method of ALAssetRepresentation.
This gives you the original RAW image data of your image and also makes it possible to use a buffer to process the image instead of reading the image into memory all at once.
And of course you can always generate NSData from the getBytes method.

Cheers,

Hendrik

Comment: Apple mentioned this when I asked them, could you give me any code examples that I could get an idea on where to start. How would I define the length in the getBytes method due to the fact that my added message will be longer than the image data. Is there an end of file length variable?

Comment: Nvm, I updated my original post with the code sample I found that worked. Thank you very much for the suggestion. Both of these answers gave me NSData from an image from the image picker but this one was able to give me the whole file and not just the NSData of the image.

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to do this in iOS 10 using the PHPhotoLibrary that is the class replacing AssetLibrary?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have your `ALAsset`, you should be able to get an `NSData` of the default representation using the following:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[asset defaultRepresentation] url]];
```

Comment: This gives me the NSData of the image but gets rid of the NSData that is appended to the image after the image code ends. I know the appended data is in the image as it shows up when emailed to the computer and viewed as a text file. Your code however DOES give the NSData version of an image picker image, so for anyone else that needs NSData from an image in the image picker, this method WILL work. In the context of what I'm looking for however this does not work. If you have any ideas on how to get the full file let me know.